# how to do system() without relaying stdout in perl

Tags: perl

How can I in perl make

system("xcodebuild");

only relay stderr, and not stdout.  (xcodebuild has an enormous amount of verbosity that I want to get rid of, but when something goes wrong, I still want to know what it was)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirect the standard output to `/dev/null`:

```
system("xcodebuild >/dev/null") == 0
  or warn "$0: xcodebuild exited " . ($? >> 8) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
system("xcodebuild >> /dev/null");
```

...assuming, of course, that you're getting all the stderr stuff with your current syscall mechanism.  Otherwise, you'll need to redirect stdout to devnull and stderr to stdout.